# IOKit/pwr_mgt/IOPMLib.h not found

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I've just downloaded an open source project (Siphon [link for download the source code](https://code.google.com/p/siphon/source/checkout)) and I am trying to run it on the simulator, but I get this error `IOKit/pwr_mgt/IOPMLib.h not found`.
What's the problem?
(I've got `XCode 5.1` and the app **deployment target** is `iOS 7.1`)

Comment: did you got the solutions for this issue